# Not able to login in neo4j hosted in docker on gcp

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, neo4j

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8evM2.jpg)I have a dockerized deployment of neo4j on the google cloud platform. I am able to bring up the UI of neo4j on 127.0.0.1/7474 and I am forwarding the port on my local PC where I am able to access the UI but not able to authenticate neo4j.

here's my docker file

```
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.1.0
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.1.0
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 100

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.1.0
    container_name: schema-registry
    ports: 
      - 8081:8081
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092

  kafka-connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:6.1.0
    container_name: kafka-connect
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:29092"
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "kafka-connect"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: "INFO"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_APPENDER_STDOUT_LAYOUT_CONVERSIONPATTERN: "[%d] %p %X{connector.context}%m (%c:%L)%n"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: '/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components/'
    command: 
      - bash 
      - -c 
      - |
        echo "Installing connector plugins"
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc:10.0.2
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir:2.0.60
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt streamthoughts/kafka-connect-file-pulse:1.5.0
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt neo4j/kafka-connect-neo4j:1.0.0
        
        #
        # -----------
        # Launch the Kafka Connect worker
        /etc/confluent/docker/run &
        #
        # Don't exit
        sleep infinity
    volumes:
      - $PWD/data:/data

  ksqldb:
    image: confluentinc/ksqldb-server:0.15.0
    container_name: ksqldb
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - kafka-connect
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      KSQL_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8088
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
      KSQL_KSQL_CONNECT_URL: http://kafka-connect:8083
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      KSQL_KSQL_SERVICE_ID: confluent_rmoff_01
      KSQL_KSQL_HIDDEN_TOPICS: '^_.*'

  postgres:
    # *-----------------------------*
    # To connect to the DB: 
    #   docker exec -it postgres bash -c 'psql -U $POSTGRES_USER $POSTGRES_DB'
    # *-----------------------------*
    image: postgres:12
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

  kafkacat:
    image: edenhill/kafkacat:1.6.0
    container_name: kafkacat
    links:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    entrypoint: 
      - /bin/sh 
      - -c 
      - |
        apk add jq; 
        while [ 1 -eq 1 ];do sleep 60;done
        
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:3.5
    hostname: neo4j
    container_name: neo4j
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7687:7687"
    environment:
      NEO4J_AUTH: neo4j/connect
      NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_max__size: 8G
      NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted: "apoc.*,algo.*"
      NEO4J_apoc_export_file_enabled: "true"
      NEO4J_kafka_zookeeper_connect: zookeeper:2181
      NEO4J_kafka_bootstrap_servers: broker:9093
    volumes:
      - $PWD/nodes_2k19/neo4j/plugins:/plugins
      - $PWD/nodes_2k19/neo4j/scripts:/scripts
      - $PWD/nodes_2k19/neo4j/docker-entrypoint.sh:/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

I have made changes in neo4j.conf file that is suggested on the other StackOverflow answers.

Comment: Did you look at what the development console has to say about the error as proposed in the error you are getting? The changes that you made to the neo4j.conf - was it to set the dbms.connector.bolt.address or dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address?

Comment: `I changed bolt_address and the console saying WebSocket connection to ws://localhost:7474 failed @jabbson

Comment: It looks like different users have had success with different approaches depending on the underlying issue. There's a thread of what people have done to fix it [here](https://community.neo4j.com/t/explanation-of-error-websocket-connection-failure-due-to-security-constraints-in-your-web-browser-the-reason-for-the-failure-is-not-available-to-this-neo4j-driver/259/10) if you haven't found it yet:

Comment: I looked at all the fixes and also tried to change neo4j.conf as solution given in that site but still getting the following error:
 ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common reasons include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL or temporary network problems.  @SimonThordal